# mac asking password after cd in terminal

Tags: terminal, password, command-line

Recently my mac has started asking me for a password after I use `cd` in Terminal.app (haven't tested other term apps).

strangely though, if I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> when the passowrd is asked, the question goes away and I'm left in the dir I was `cd`-ing to (as one would expect).

how can I find out what this password is needed for or how to stop this?
I'm using `zsh`

**EDIT:**

The terminal asks for a password at random moments, for random directories. Not a clue as to any pattern. The output is basically:

```
cd ~/Downloads
Password:
```

I think this started happening after I installed [JewelryBox.app](http://jewelrybox.unfiniti.com/)

Comment: A few more details would probably be helpful here. Does it happen with all `cd` commands or only for specific directories? If the second, any idea on what these have in common and/or what puts them apart from the others? Also posting a screenshot (or a text copy) of the message (and the `cd` part) would give some hints.

Comment: Can you write some output in Terminal like `whence cd`, `which cd`, `echo $SHELL`. It seems this command is different than builtin

Comment: `echo $SHELL` gives `/bin/zsh` and `which` says `cd: shell built-in command`. `whence cd` just says `cd`. I remmeber there is a `zsh` thing you can enable as to see all the commands executed when you do something, `xset` or something like that but I cannot remember exactly what.

Comment: `set -x` that was it. `cd`-ing to a dir outputs a lot stuff, including a lot of references to rvm, rubies, ... so I think the culprit must be JewelryBox or any of it's installed rvms.

Comment: @romeovs - consider adding an answer to your question below to help those who find this question in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can run `set -x` to make zsh print a trace of every command it executes. When a command is executed by a function, the function name is printed. Run `set +x` to stop printing traces.

If something is happening when you use the `cd` command, it can be because this is an alias or function. Check with `type cd`.

Zsh has a built-in feature to hook onto the `cd` command, so wrappers around the built-in command are rarely used. If the function [`chpwd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-chpwd) exists, zsh runs it immediately after changing the directory. Check what the `chpwd` function does with `which chpwd`.

There are also hooks that run before and after every command: the [`preexec`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-preexec) and [`precmd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-precmd) functions. Furthermore, all these hooks have an array version, which is an array of function names. Check these arrays with `echo $chpwd_functions`, and if there is a function, look at its code.